# "Braune Augen" to substantive or adjective

Tags: noun, adjective

Is it possible to transform the phrase "braune Augen" into substantive or at least into adjective? How in that case a person with brown eyes could be called in one word?

---

What's the mechanism of transforming? How is it possible to form the other adjectives with the suffix -ig?

Comment: `braunäugig` as adjektive, with as substantive I have to surrender.

Comment: The noun 'Braunauge' is also possible to adress someone with brown eyes: "Hey, Braunauge." This is most commonly used in a rather romantic or flirty way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As bummi already commented, *having brown eyes* can be expressed as *braunäugig*. You can then use this adjective as a noun:

> Der Braunäugige lächelte.

It’s a bit unusual to define someone by their eye colour, though. Also watch out for *blauäugig*: While originally meaning *having blue eyes* in the same way as above, it can also signify *naïve* or *gullible*.

> Sie sind sehr blauäugig an die Sache herangegangen.

The noun *Blauäugigkeit* actually exclusively denotes *naïveté*. (See [Why is "blauäugig" used with a negative connotation?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3595) for the origin of this change of meaning.)

---

Generally speaking, *-ig* is a productive suffix that can be used to derive adjectives from nouns, and often meaning *having …* or *exhibiting …*. Examples include:

> Maß – mäßig, Wasser – wäßrig, Sonne – sonnig, Suff – süffig, Gewicht – gewichtig.

As you can see, unstressed *e* is sometimes dropped from the noun, and the suffix may cause umlaut, though not always.

Extensions to the noun can in some cases be packed into the adjective, too, as in *braunäugig* (*braune Augen*) or *außerhäusig* (*außer Haus*).